# Enable https in cartodb installation

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, docker, cartodb

I am using this image https://github.com/sverhoeven/docker-cartodb to start my own container, and then created a reverse proxy by nginx to enable ssl.

The ssl website pulls up but the problem is carto does not detect the change in protocol, and i am getting mixed content warning due to api requests by cbd.js on HTTP protocol.

for example: http://carto.gq/user/dev/api/v1/viz/?tag_name=&q=&page=1&type=&exclude_shared=false&per_page=20&locked=&tags=&shared=no&only_liked=false&order=updated_at&types=table&exclude_raster=true.

What file I should to change the protocol of api calls, here is my installation https://carto.gq .

Answer (score 0):

Enable SSL

## Enable Nginx on the server and redirect all traffic to ssl (ubuntu):

1. Install Nginx

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nginx
   ```
2. Install certbot-nginx

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python-certbot-nginx
   ```

   Now follow the instructions on screen as they appear
3. Edit Nginx File

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
   ```

   Now Find the existing server_name line and replace the underscore, _, with 
   your domain name:

   ```
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   ```

   Now replace the block below:

   ```
   location / {
   …………………………
   }
   ```

   With this given below and as nginx-change.txt in docs folder

   ```
   client_max_body_size 150M;

   location / {
           # First attempt to serve request as file, then
           # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
           #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
   }
   ```
4. Then, verify the syntax and reload Nginx to load the new configuration.

   ```
   sudo nginx -t
   sudo systemctl reload nginx
   ```
5. Skip Firewall for now will add later.
6. Obtaining an SSL Certificate

   ```
   sudo certbot --nginx -d carto.ml -d www.carto.ml
   ```

   Follow the instructions on Screen after this is done over

## Enable SSL on a carto container, after it is running on 8088 internal port:

1. Start container

   ```
   docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8088:80 -h carto.ml sandeepgadhwal/cartodb
   ```
2. Get Container ID

   ```
   docker ps -a
   ```

   example: 99718a6233b9
3. Connect to container bash

   ```
   docker exec -it {containerid} /bin/bash
   ```

   example: docker exec -it ac2ce1a67df3 /bin/bash
4. Install missing components

   ```
   apt-get install nano
   ```
5. Edit baseurl in rails file.

   ```
   nano cartodb/app/models/user/user_decorator.rb
   ```

   you’ll need to edit line 100, 
   replace base_url: public_url, with base_url: public_url.sub('http','https')
   This will update the user_data.base_urlglobal which cdb.js uses to build 
   many of the api calls
6. Edit Api protocols and portd in app_config.yml you can find the same in 
   docker-cartodb folder.

   ```
   nano /cartodb/config/app_config.yml
   ```

   you’ll need to edit line 35,37,40,42,46,49,51,54,258,,259,261,262.
   replace port to 443 or https port of your server, replace http to https
   This will update the api_urls for sql and maps Api.
7. get out of editor and the bash

   ```
   Press ctrl + c to exit
   ```

   Confirm write to file by pressing Y and pressing enter

   Then to exit bash

   ```
   press ctrl + q + p
   ```
8. Restart Container

   ```
   docker restart {containerid}
   ```